# XAML arguments for Click event

Tags: c#, events, xaml

I have the following XAML:

```
<Button Name="btnJeans" Click="btnJeans_Click" Padding="-1" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17" Name="jeansItem">
        <!--Replace rectangle with image-->
        <Image Height="119" Width="82" Source="{Binding Image}" Margin="12,0,9,0"/>
        <StackPanel Width="311">                                    
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

However, btnJeans_Click needs to pass "{Binding Name}" as an argument.

How would I do this?
I'm developing for Windows Phone 7.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative on the pc is to get get the DataContext from the click event args e.g.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      var record = ((Button)e.OriginalSource).DataContext;
      MessageBox.Show("Do something with " + record.ToString()); 
    }
```

this might be applicable to the phone as well?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use a command instead of a button click event to do this so you can do:

```
<Button Name="btnJeans" Command="{Binding Path=ButtonClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Name}">
    ...
</Button>
```

You'll then need to expose ButtonClickCommand as a ICommand object.

How to do this will depend on the structure of the rest of your application.  E.g. Using MVVM pattern etc.

Comment: The property 'Command' was not found in type 'Button'. The same goes for the Parameters

Comment: That's odd.  I just put your code into a simple WPF window, and I could add the Command and CommandParameter properties to Button.  Looking at MSDN they seem to be there for Silverlight as well, so that can't be the problem.

Comment: Here is the MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.command(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: I should probably mention that I'm developing for the Windows Phone 7 platform

Comment: Apparently Command is supported in SL4... but not on WP7 :( (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.command%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Then, would there be another way to do this?

Comment: I've never used WP7, so I don't know the best solution.  I know there are a number of libraries (MVVM Light, Caliburn.Micro?) which are designed to work around some of the missing bits.  Maybe these can provide a solution for you.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway. Those libs don't really give that functionality so I'll wait for another answer.

Answer (score 0):

XAML allows for you to set the BindingContext of a button.

See the example below that refers to the Id property of the object which will be passed to the click handler.

```
    <Button Name="btnJeans" Click="btnJeans_Click" Padding="-1" BindingContext="{Binding Id}">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17" Name="jeansItem">
    <!--Replace rectangle with image-->
    <Image Height="119" Width="82" Source="{Binding Image}" Margin="12,0,9,0"/>
    <StackPanel Width="311">                                    
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

You can then access the property using the sender's BindingContext object. In the example you can refer to id property within the handler.

```
    private void btnJeans_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        var id = button.BindingContext;

    }
```